# C# LINQ to flatten parent list and two nested children lists and populate it to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I have this code that I woud like to populate to a datagridview in windows form c#

```
   public class Person
   {
       public string Nom { get; set; }
       public string Prenom { get; set; }
   }

    public class Phone
    {
        public int PhoneId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public int EmailId { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contacts
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public Person Contact { get; set; }
        public List<Phone> Telephone { get; set; } 
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }

    }
```

I have this code that works fine but I cannot get it to work to show the emails as well

```
    var result = c.SelectMany(x => x.Telephone, (x, y) => 
new { x.ContactId, x.Contact.Nom, x.Contact.Prenom, y.PhoneNumber }).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

[image: Here is an image of what I have]

Comment: What do you mean ***I cannot get it to work to show the emails***? Give an example.

Comment: When I do it like that in the datagridview it show the name, last name and the phone number but I want it to show the emails as well

Comment: In the same grid view? If so, how do you connect an email and a phone? Let's say one person has 1 phone and 3 emails, how do you connect them?

Comment: I do not want to connect them I just want it to show just like the other properties shows in the data gridview. I wanted to show a photo but I don't see how to upload it

Comment: Ok, so you want to show the emails just like the phones one?

Comment: @GellioGao Exactly.

Comment: Check out my answer, please.

Comment: @JohnG List<Contacts> c = new List<Contacts>

Comment: Is this question specific to using LINQ or just how to display all the info properly? Obviously, you need to “flatten” the data, however, it would appear to me that if “Jeff” as three (3) phone numbers and five (5) email addresses, then “Jeff” would have five rows of data. Why duplicate the “Jeff” data 5 times? Would it not be more appropriate to have ONE (1) row of “Jeff” with all phone numbers in ONE (1) cell and ALL the Email addresses in one cell?

Comment: @JohnG it is basically about displaying all the properties and yes displaying all the phones and emails that belongs to one contact to a datagridviewcombobox would be my next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using a `List<myClass>` as a `DataSource` to the grid is that the grid will not display properties of `myClass` that are collections. Like the `Telephone` and `Emails` lists. It will display a Class, however, it will default and use the classes `ToString` method and display that into a "single" column.

In your example, using the `Contacts` Class as a `List<Contacts>` as a `DataSource` to the grid, I am sure you are aware that neither the `Person` object is displayed properly since it is a Class nor is  the Phone and Email objects displayed because they are collections of objects.

In this example, the `Person` object may display as a column in the grid, however, it will display something like… “SolutionName.Person.” If `Person` had an overridden `ToString` method then it would display what that method returned. However, even with an overridden `ToString` method, it will NOT “split” the `Person` object into two columns… one for `Nom` and the other `Prenom`… your code would need to do this.

In the case of the phone numbers and emails… no column will be generated for those properties because they are “collection” properties and the grid does not know how to put “multiple” items into a single cell. This is why they are ignored.

In addition, as I commented, it seems like a poor UI idea to “repeat” the `Nom` and `Prenom` data for x number of rows. IMO, one row for each `Person` and if that person has multiple phone numbers and emails, then add ALL the phone numbers and emails such that they will be in a SINGLE cell. This will remove the redundant data duplication.

So, given this… how can we “flatten” the data so we can get both `Person` properties to display in two different columns and also have ALL the phone numbers in a single cell and ALL the email addresses in a single cell?

One possible solution follows.

First, I suggest you simply “add” these properties to the `Contacts` class. In the `Contact` class we will add the properties to the class that simply return the `Person`s `Nom` and `Prenom` properties.

This will solve the issue of displaying the `Nom` and `Prenom` properties as two different columns in the grid. However, we still have the “collection” problem with the `PhoneNumbers` and the `EmailAddresses.`

In this case, one solution is to add a `string` property to the `Contacts` class and have it return a single string with ALL the phone numbers and another `string` property that returns all the `Emails` as a single `string.` Once this is done, then the grid WILL display those properties since it is single string and not a “collection” of strings.

So, some changes are needed in the `Contacts` class. Below is an example of what is described above. Note, I CHANGED the class name to `Contact` instead of `Contacts` and I CHANGED the `Person` property name to `ThePerson` instead of `Contact.` So, you need to adjust your code accordingly.

This updated `Contact` class may look something like…

```
public class Contact {
  public int ContactId { get; set; }
  public Person ThePerson { get; set; }
  public List<Phone> Telephone { get; set; }
  public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }

  public string PhoneNumbers {
    get {
      if (Telephone == null) {
        return "";
      }
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < Telephone.Count; i++) {
        sb.Append(Telephone[i].PhoneNumber.ToString());
        if (i < Telephone.Count - 1) {
          sb.AppendLine();
        }
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }

  public string EmailAddresses {
    get {
      if (Emails == null) {
        return "";
      }
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < Emails.Count; i++) {
        sb.Append(Emails[i].EmailAddress.ToString());
        if (i < Emails.Count - 1) {
          sb.AppendLine();
        }
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }

  public string Nom {
    get {
      if (ThePerson == null) {
        return "";
      }
      return ThePerson.Nom;
    }
  }

  public string Prenom {
    get {
      if (ThePerson == null) {
        return "";
      }
      return ThePerson.Prenom;
    }
  }
}
```

As described previously, we added two properties called `Nom` and `Prenom` and they simply return those properties from the `ThePerson` object. This will make a column for both properties.

Next, we have the added `PhoneNumbers` and `EmailAddresses` properties. In this case, we need to loop through all the phone numbers and add each phone number to a single string. In this case, each phone number will be on a single line, so we will need to adjust the grids row heights to accommodate however many lines there are. Otherwise, some phone numbers may be cut off in the cells display. This same idea is used for the Email addresses.

Next, we need to manually add the columns to the grid. Then tell the grid to not auto generate the columns since we obviously have already added them. The key property in each column will be its `DataPropertyName`. This property tells the grid “which” property to display in the column given a `DataSource`. In this case, we want to set the first columns `DataPropertyName` to `ContactID`, the second column to `Nom`, third to `Prenom`, fourth to `PhoneNumbers` and finally the last to `EmaillAddresses`. To help a method is created to return a column with the given properties… Something like…

```
private DataGridViewColumn GetDGVCol(string colName, string dataPropertyName, string headerText) {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  col.Name = colName;
  col.DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName;
  col.HeaderText = headerText;
  return col;
}
```

To use the above helper in this example, I created an additional method that adds the columns to the grid as described.

```
private void AddDGV_Columns() {
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("ContactID", "ContactID", "ContactID"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("Nom", "Nom", "Nom"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("Prenom", "Prenom", "Prenom"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("PhoneNumbers", "PhoneNumbers", "PhoneNumbers"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("EmailAddresses", "EmailAddresses", "EmailAddresses"));
  dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
  dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
}
```

Above we mate all the columns to a property in the `Contacts` class, then set the cells wrap mode to accommodate multiple lines in the `PhoneNumers` and `EmailAddresses` properties. In addition to auto sizing the column width to show all the data.

To make a complete example, the code below should demonstrate what is described above. NOTE, I have changed some class names and property names and you will need to adjust your code to fit mine or change my code to fit yours.

[image]

```
List<Contact> Contacts;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Contacts = GetContacts();
  AddDGV_Columns();
  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = Contacts;
}

private void AddDGV_Columns() {
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("ContactID", "ContactID", "ContactID"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("Nom", "Nom", "Nom"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("Prenom", "Prenom", "Prenom"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("PhoneNumbers", "PhoneNumbers", "PhoneNumbers"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetDGVCol("EmailAddresses", "EmailAddresses", "EmailAddresses"));
  dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
  dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
  dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
}

private DataGridViewColumn GetDGVCol(string colName, string dataPropertyName, string headerText) {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  col.Name = colName;
  col.DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName;
  col.HeaderText = headerText;
  return col;
}



private List<Contact> GetContacts() {
  List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
  List<Phone> PhoneNumbers = new List<Phone>();
  Phone pn = new Phone { PhoneId = 1, PhoneNumber = "111-11-11" };
  PhoneNumbers.Add(pn);
  pn = new Phone { PhoneId = 2, PhoneNumber = "222-22-22" };
  PhoneNumbers.Add(pn);
  pn = new Phone { PhoneId = 3, PhoneNumber = "222-22-22" };
  PhoneNumbers.Add(pn);
  Person = new Person { Nom = "Jeff", Prenom = "Prosper" };
  List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();
  Email em = new Email { EmailId = 1, EmailAddress = "email1@someISP.com" };
  emails.Add(em);
  em = new Email { EmailId = 2, EmailAddress = "email2@someISP.com" };
  emails.Add(em);
  Contact newC = new Contact { ContactId = 1, Telephone = PhoneNumbers, Emails = emails, ThePerson = person };
  Contacts.Add(newC);
  person = new Person { Nom = "Jimmy", Prenom = "Gean" };
  PhoneNumbers = new List<Phone>();
  pn = new Phone { PhoneId = 1, PhoneNumber = "333-33-33" };
  PhoneNumbers.Add(pn);
  emails = new List<Email>();
  em = new Email { EmailId = 1, EmailAddress = "emailXX1@someISP.com" };
  emails.Add(em);
  em = new Email { EmailId = 2, EmailAddress = "emailXX2@someISP.com" };
  emails.Add(em);
  newC = new Contact { ContactId = 2, Telephone = PhoneNumbers, Emails = emails, ThePerson = person };
  Contacts.Add(newC);
  return Contacts;
}
```

***Edit as per Enigmativity's comment.***

As @Enigmativity notes a more succinct approach could be used like below. You would use these properties below as opposed to the above properties. Thanks, Enigmativity

```
public string PhoneNumbers => Telephone == null ? "" : String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Telephone.Select(x => x.PhoneNumber));

public string EmailAddresses => Emails == null ? "" : String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Emails.Select(x => x.EmailAddress));

public string Nom => ThePerson == null ? "" : ThePerson.Nom;

public string Prenom => ThePerson == null ? "" : ThePerson.Prenom;
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much bro and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: The only problem now is it throw an exception if the contact does not have any email.

Comment: I added the checks for a `null` Telephone or Emails list. Sorry they should have been there to begin with. Please see the edited code for the `PhoneNumbers` and `EmailAddresses` properties. The same applies to the `Nom` and `Prenom`.

Comment: You could write those properties a lot more succinctly like `public string PhoneNumbers => Telephone == null ? "" : String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Telephone.Select(x => x.PhoneNumber));` and `public string Nom => ThePerson?.Nom ?? "";`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you mean, it could be implemented like below:

```
var result = c.SelectMany(
    // Here we merge phone and email together, give null if no value for either.
    x => Enumerable.Range(0, new[] { x.Emails.Count, x.Telephone.Count }.Max())
        .Select(n => new { Phone = x.Telephone.ElementAtOrDefault(n), Email = x.Emails.ElementAtOrDefault(n) }), 
    // Select phone and email at the same row.
    (x, y) => new { x.ContactId, x.Contact.Nom, x.Contact.Prenom, y.Phone?.PhoneNumber, y.Email?.EmailAddress })
.ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

Comment: In this case it will only show the emails in the datagridview not the phones, but I want to show both.

Comment: That's what I asked you, how do you know which email appears after which phone if you have multiple emails and phones?

Comment: It does not matter as long as it is for the same contact

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out, please.

Comment: It gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception

Comment: I've fixed it, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be through the *query syntax* to perform a similar `SelectMany` on the `Email` enumerable and then *join* on the applicable criteria (e.g, the same contact identifier)

```
var phoneNumbers = c.SelectMany(c => c.Telephone, (contact, phone) => new { contact.ContactId, contact.Contact.Nom, contact.Contact.Prenom, phone.PhoneNumber });
var result = from phone in phoneNumbers
             // return back join condition (e.g, ContactId) and email address
             from email in c.SelectMany(c => c.Emails, (contact, email) => new { contact.ContactId, email.EmailAddress } )
             where email.ContactId == phone.ContactId
             select new { phone.ContactId, phone.Nom, phone.Prenom, email.EmailAddress, phone.PhoneNumber };

emailGrid.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: @LikilikZipzip What specifically does not work in the above example?

Comment: When I run it nothing shows in the Data Grid view.

Comment: One explicit difference from this example from the one you've tried earlier was the explicit `.ToList()` invocation - it's possible that you would need to add it here for it to execute and render in the Data View (edited the post for clarity); otherwise, I'm not sure why the above would not work as it shows the expected results in LINQPad.